# Converting a Crosstab Dataframe into a single one (stacked)

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have made the following cross-tab table:

```
foo = pd.Categorical(['a', 'b'], categories=['a', 'b', 'c'])
bar = pd.Categorical(['d', 'e'], categories=['d', 'e', 'f'])
pd.crosstab(foo, bar)
```

that gives:

```
col_0  d  e
row_0      
a      1  0
b      0  1
```

I want to convert above into a single stacked table such that I get:

```
  row_0  tot d  tot e
0     a      1      0
1     b      0      1
```

namely the header of the column `d` and `e` is changed to `tot d` and `tot e` and `row_0` is now a column. So far I do this by saving the cross-tab version into excel and impose the changes by hand and the import it. But I'm sure there should be a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(foo, bar)
   
df = df.add_prefix('tot ').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1) 
print (df)
  row_0  tot d  tot e
0     a      1      0
1     b      0      1
```